# How to append message to unix mailbox in java?

Tags: java, linux, email

I'd like to append message to unix mailbox file (file like /var/mail/username). How should I do that? How are messages separated there? Is there any specification on the net?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this depends on the mailbox that you are using as there are several of them.

I guess the best point to start would be here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple incompatible formats for this, but the basic format that should be followed is described in [RFC 4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155), which contains the basic rules in Appendix A, and also links to [the qmail man page for mbox](http://qmail.org./man/man5/mbox.html) for further description of some of the variations.

You might be able to get information on the specific format used on your system by looking at your own system's man page for mbox and/or mail.  But your system won't necessarily even have these man pages.